# "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false""

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar is given me error "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false"" on else if block. any thoughts please?

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

@ServiceActivator(channel = "channel")
public void loadMessage(Message<?> message) throws InterruptedException {
    if (!valid(message)) {
        return;
    }
 }

        private void valid(Message<?> message){

                if (Objects.isNull(message)) {
                     log.error("*******************");

                } else if (Objects.isNull(message.getPayload())) {
                        log.error("*******************")
                } else {
                    //business logic
                }

        }
```

I tried to use == operator to validate else if conditions. but still getting same error.

Comment: in last else condition, casting with string .. (String)message.getpayload().

Comment: Is `getPayload` marked `@Nonnull`?

Comment: no. directly reading message and validating through valid method.

Comment: Not the primary issue but```valid()``` as you have it here returns no value, so you can't test whether that no-value is true or false.

Comment: looking at the constructor for ```GenericMessage``` (which implements the ```Message``` interface), the payload is described as 'never null'.  So maybe your style checker believes that to be true for all messages. Maybe it is. I don't use that framework so I can't say.  If you can't construct a message with a null payload, you'll never get null from ```getPayload```.

Comment: Why would you use `isNull()` instead of `== null`?

Comment: If your message is a `GenericMessage` instance then according to spring doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/support/GenericMessage.html) "payload - the message payload (never null)" hence if you are sure your payload is a String then cast it and use `isEmpty`.

Comment: @muaz No, use `Message<String>` instead.

Comment: @another-dave, as I am using Message interface not Generic Interface. still Message<?> will call internally to Generic Message interface and mark not null to getPayload? little confused.

Comment: @shmosel, tried to == null also. it behaving same.

Comment: @chrylis, this would be my last option to convert Message<?> to Message<String>.

Comment: Well, my advice would be to ditch Sonar :-). There's nothing actually wrong with testing for null (i.e., the code works as written) it's just that Sonar thinks you don't need it.